# Are online courses regarded as the equivalent of professional experience?

Tags: work-experience, software-development, skills, junior, degree

My background is in Electrical and Electronic Engineering.

Last year I paid and attended [android developer nano-degree by google](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-developer-nanodegree-by-google--nd801) course.

At the end of it I uploaded my [capstone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=theo.easy.news) project on play store.

Now I am watching another course on Udemy called **NodeJS - The Complete Guide (incl. MVC, REST APIs, GraphQL)** which teaches you how to create node.js. applications. I have also attended two other Udemy courses regarding Android Development.

I applied for various android role positions, but didn't hear anything back. I was expected at least to be interviewed on my capstone's project code which is also in [github](https://github.com/theo82/Capstone-Udacity-Android-Nanodegree). The code has been reviewed and works cool. Of course, I need to use at some point patterns like RxJava and MVVM.

But is all this considered as **commercial experience** or I wasted my money watching online courses?

Comment: You know that online courses are just a tool to help you in learning something or gaining skills and other stuffs, getting a certificate from udemy or others has nothing to do with what you can do, they can't even know if you really completed that or did someone passed the test for you. If you want to pay something, then go for certificates, they'll help you in gaining skills and they're more trust in interviews than online courses

Comment: I believe you mean to ask about professional experience, rather than commercial experience.

Comment: @Noblesse I have a Java SE 6 certication from Oracle which I gained back in 2012. The next level costs like 2000 Euros or something I think.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh What's the difference? Many people think both professional and commercial experience are the same.

Comment: @Theo nothing much, it's the former which is the de-facto lingo.

Comment: There has been a lot of changes since Java 6, and now Java 12 beta version has been released so might think about getting at least Java 8 Certificate. Another thing I need to say that it's not just about a certificate about programming skills but also management and other things, SCRUM for example. There are tons of certificate out there you just need to know what you wanna do and what would you like to have

Comment: @Noblesse I use streams and lamda expression which were introduced in Java 8 so I am aware if the new changes. Do you have any programming certifications?

Comment: Theo - IMHO, the point @Noblesse is making is perfectly valid, that the technology certification you have is now 7 years old and the technology has moved on considerably since then.  You need to stay relevant and keep learning new skills. Recruiters and hiring managers will see you as having zero relevant commercial experience and that you have built a couple of hobby projects which aren't groundbreaking but merely collate data from multiple sources and put inside a wrapper.

Comment: it might replace a university degree in the requirements if it does give the required background, but it doesn't replace a professional experience by any means. Follow up by interesting projects and it will be considered as a professional experience.

Comment: The simple answer is no, they are a joke.

Comment: Do you know how many applicants applied to the job posting?  The last online job posting I applied to had over 70 applicants and it was for a very specific career path that's particularly difficult to get into.  If you're applying through a job search website then it gets even more difficult to land that job since you compete against potentially hundreds of other applicants.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a bit of a false dichotomy in your final question.

First of all, training courses are not considered professional (or commercial) experience, because it does not meet the definition of professional experience. There may be courses where you may have a placement within a professional environment, working on professional project, and that may be muddying the water a little, but they are very rare.

Professional experience means to be employed in the profession in question. There are a range of implications that step from that. Commercial experience implies that you've worked on a product that has seen some degree of commercialisation (in other words, you sold it to someone.) Note that sticking an app on an App Store is likely to count for very little given how trivial that is to do. Get a large number of downloads, and it may be a different story.

> But is all this considered as commercial experience or I wasted my money watching online courses?

If you end goal was to gain commercial experience, then you have (probably) not reached that goal by doing a Udacity course, but that doesn't necessarily mean you wasted your money.

If you learnt valuable skills as part of that course, it makes you more employable. If the course is recognised by the person making the hiring decision, you're even more employable.

Just because some large organisation "accredits" a course doesn't mean that it is held in universal regard.

Also, I just want to point out, that even widely-known certification authorities are considered as useless by some people, for various reasons. Just as degrees are considered the same by some people too.

Comment: Regarding teh last paragraph - you're very right. It does not really matter much whether that was a on-premise course or an online MOOC.

Answer (score 6):

It's good to have a certain course completed from a widely-known certification authority (online of offline) and have the certificate, but most of the time, that counts towards your proficiency level and theoretical knowledge.

Majority of the cases, they are **not** considered as professional experience.

If you have pet-projects which you can showcase, that adds to the value, sure.

- If you're searching for entry-level positions (fresh out of college), they may look very good on your CV.
- However, if you're having certain experience, and the course is not directly related to your field/ domain of work experience, the online certifications are seldom worthy of *substantial* influence alone.

Comment: Yes but the Udacity course is accredited by Google. So...

Comment: @Theo the course being google-accredited improves the value of the course - but it's still a course, courses and certifications are generally good things but they aren't the same thing as professional experience and you can't equate the two

Answer (score 3):

No. Not at all. They are two different things.
Online courses are good for you if they teach something useful but they are not professional experience. In any case, they would be comparable to formal education, but it's still not quite like that.

In my experience, the best use of online courses is keeping your work rather than getting one, but in any case, if your question is "But is all this considered as commercial experience or I wasted my money watching online courses?" then you answered the question yourself, as I think it's accurate to infer that you didn't learn any skill (in that case, why should companies take it into account?).